# How to remove elements from javascript array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a java script array which consist of some elements ,now i want to remove element by value from my array ,I am posting my code

```
 var strDate = [2015-10-26,2015-10-27,2015-10-28,2015-10-29,2015-10-30,2015-10-31,2015-11-01];

 var index = strDate.indexOf(new Date(calEvent.start).toISOString().slice(0, 10));
                //strDate.splice(new Date(calEvent.start).toISOString().slice(0, 10));
delete strDate[index];
```

how to delete elements in an arry

Comment: You should look at `Array.prototype.splice()`

Comment: don't use `delete` to remove element from array use `splice`

Comment: @ how i will modify my code?

Comment: `strDate.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: @Tushar not removing the values

Comment: Check if the index is correct, try `var index = strDate.indexOf(new Date(calEvent.start).toISOString()); strDate.splice(index, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `splice()` function. So if you want to remove the item at index 5, you would type `strDate.splice(5,1);`  The `1` being how many items to remove starting at that index.

You may want to put your items in the array in quotation marks as they are being evaluated as integers and being subtracted from each other. IE: Year - Month - Date